# Roundoff numbers

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

How to round off the number 1452.1589758654654654678798751268549874654657497 & 1452.8589758654654654678798751268549874654657497 to next nearest number. After roundoff I need that number to be 1453 (not 1452).

`Math.Round(1452.1589758654654654678798751268549874654657497, 0)` but this just round off to 1452.

if you're not clear what I'm asking please comment below.

Comment: That's not rounding, that's the 'ceiling' function.

Comment: you mean, `Math.Ceiling` right ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Math.Ceiling will return an integer that is larger. (Towards + infinity)
- Math.Floor will return an integer that is smaller. (Towards - infinity)
- Math.Round will return an integer that is rounded (it's value will
  depend on how it is called).

If you want a number that is larger, use Math.Ceiling.  MSDN has complete details on all 3 of the built in .net framework methods.

Comment: You should be careful when the argument could be negative: Math.Floor(-3.5) is -4, which is larger in magnitude. It is perhaps clearer to describe it as rounding towards negative infinity,

Comment: I've updated the answer but -4 < -3 = true would be assumed.